# Hide same row value based on condition in angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ng-if

[image]

> code for popup,how to write *ngIf condition to hide same row group and display other group .Here i am passing and displaying group, i just need to hide respective request group. GroupRequestDesc have all group values.

```
 <tr>
    <td *ngFor="let value of GroupRequestDesc;let $index=index " style="padding-right: 15px;">                             
       <label for="checkbox_group2" class="checkbox cb_pad" style="width: 180px;display:inline-block;">
           <input id="checkbox_group2" type="checkbox" value="{{value.nxReqGroupId}}" (change)="checkboxVisibility(value.ReqGroupId,$event)"/><i class="skin"></i><span>{{value.nxReqGroupDesc}}</span>
       </label>
    </td>
<tr>
```

> And here is my function through which I am passing details to the
>   popup for display:

```
passReqIdforcopytogroup(nxRequestId,solutionData,groupData){
        this.ReqId = RequestId;
        this.ReqGroupId = groupData;
        this.GroupRequestDesc = groupData;
        this.SolutionId = solutionData.SolutionId;
        this.ReqGroupName = solutionData.ReqGroupName;
    }
```

Here what i am trying to achieve is that when i click on submit button respective request group should not display in next coming popup rest all other group should display in popup.how can i achieve that please someone help me on this.
On Click of submit I am displaying popup which should display remain group

Comment: can you provide us a stackblitz with an example of what you are trying to do :) ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp9gcu   this link has basic flow. each request have button. onclick of that i am displaying popup. in that i want to hide group which is in same row of button click... i haven't included popup and button here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is HTML code:

```js
  passDataToPopup(group, reqId){
    console.log(group, reqId);
    let remainingGroups = group.filter(ele=> ele.ReqId != reqId);
    console.log(remainingGroups, 'remaining reqestids of group');

  }
```

```html
    <td>
        <button class="btn-success" 
         (click)= "passDataToPopup(groupRowData.requestDetails, requestDetailData.ReqId)">submit</button>
    </td>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ng-if](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) for this purpose

Comment: yes i tried using it but i m not getting exact condition for the same

Comment: you can declare flag stepper and use it

Comment: what exactly should that condition be?

Comment: Hi Glenn ... on click of submit same row group need to hide and rest all group should display in popup